# Changing Entry Point of Application with VS2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, linker

I am attempting to redefine my entry point of my application to not use main() because it is clashing with some other code that I am attempting to test.

I am using a subsystem:CONSOLE, and outputting an exe. All works when it is defined as

```
int main(int argc,CHAR  **argv) {}
```

Things compile fine.

I then change it to.

```
int main_test(int argc,CHAR  **argv) {}
```

And in the visual studio Linker entry point i change it from its blank value to main_test i start getting a ton (like 3500+) of linking errors related to libcpmtd.lib and other symbols that are missing in my obj files like __stdio_common_vsscanf which obviously is a built in function that i am not actually calling anywhere.

```
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol ___mb_cur_max_func referenced in function _Getcvt    MyProject C:\Source\project\src\libcpmtd.lib(xwctomb.obj)   1
```

I get the exact same errors if i leave my function as main shown above, and just type main in as the entry point, so it makes me believe that something im doing is wrong.  Any help would be appreciated it seems like A simple problem im not sure why its so difficult.

Comment: What makes you think that `main_test()` would be recognized as a valid entry point for an executable program?

Comment: Because you can alter the entry point with /ENTRY flag and thats exactly what the flag says it does?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/entry-entry-point-symbol?view=vs-2017

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to set [entry point](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/entry-entry-point-symbol?view=vs-2017)

> Open the project's Property Pages dialog box. For details, see Setting
>   Visual C++ Project Properties.
>
> Click the Linker folder.
>
> Click the Advanced property page.
>
> Modify the Entry Point property.

and set `main_test`

After, I do not fully understand why, but it is necessary to do [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/include-force-symbol-references?view=vs-2017)

> Open the project's Property Pages dialog box. For details, see Setting
>   Visual C++ Project Properties.
>
> Click the Linker folder.
>
> Click the Input property page.
>
> Modify the Force Symbol References property.

and set `_mainCRTStartup` for x86 or `mainCRTStartup` for x64.

Or do it programmatically in yor code:

```
#pragma comment(linker, "/ENTRY:main_test")
#if defined(_M_IX86)
# pragma comment(linker, "/INCLUDE:_mainCRTStartup")
#else
# pragma comment(linker, "/INCLUDE:mainCRTStartup")
#endif

#include <iostream>    

int main() {
   std::cout << "main" << std::endl;
   return 0;
}

int main_test()
{
   std::cout << "main_test" << std::endl;
   return 0;
}
```

Output

`main_test`

Note that `main` is not a default **entry point**. The entry point for console app is `_mainCRTStartup` which calls `main`. Therefore changing the entry point you lose CRT and you have to manually implement things like command line arguments getting. For more detailed look [here](http://www.drdobbs.com/avoiding-the-visual-c-runtime-library/184416623)

**UPD**

I do not think that developing your own CRT is good decision, it will be easier to use one of the built-in entry points.

```
#pragma comment(linker, "/ENTRY:wmainCRTStartup ") // wmain will be called
//#pragma comment(linker, "/ENTRY:mainCRTStartup  ") // main will be called

#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main(int argc, char** argv) {
   for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++)
      std::cout << argv[i] << std::endl;
   return 0;
}

int wmain(int argc, wchar_t *argv[])
{
   for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++)
      std::wcout << argv[i] << std::endl;
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: This makes it compile, but my app crashes because it passes the argc and argv on to another API...debugging and argc appears to be just some giant uninitalized numbers.  Is there something else special you need to do to properly support argc,argv like in my initial post?

Comment: As i mentioned it crashes if App2(my testing app) changes its entry point.  So i tried changing my App1 entry point instead, and it just keeps complaining  with an unresolved external symbol main, even though i've checked the entry point matches my new Main_App function name and set the forced value for x64 as you specified.

Comment: @user1024792, If I get it right, mainCRTStartup have no arguments. It gets console arguments by __getmainargs func and passes arguments to `main` You are replacing `mainCRTStartup` func, no `main`! Now you need to implement the minimum content of `mainCRTStartup` in `main_test`.

Comment: So problem, even though this compiles it seems to break something related to the programs memory space/heap.  In your example can you try malloc'ing memory space?  I have a simple main function that just does char* testchar = (char*)malloc(5); that will crash the application with a memory write exception.  If i change my app back to using main() and not a custom entry point with your 2 changes it works fine and allocates properly.  Thanks for all your help!

Comment: @user1024792 This is quite expected. You rearranged the entry point and lost all the mainCRTStartup initialisation code. Correct initialization of the application is not made. I do not see any options for how to do this without mainCRTStartup code
 copying into the main_test. Need to find a more elegant solution. Look in \crt\src\vcruntime\exe_common.inl to understanding.

Comment: @user1024792, Here it explains why without CRT nemry allocation doesnt work http://www.drdobbs.com/avoiding-the-visual-c-runtime-library/184416623. You asked an interesting question, I think

Comment: This makes sense thanks for all your help.  I have sort of worked around my inital problem by just forcing the linker to ignore that there are two main functions and just use mine not the one defined in a .lib im using.  Thanks again